# ANTLR4 won't display anything in Eclipse on Mac Os x

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, antlr4

I am working on "The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference" book and i'm trying to run ArrayInit.g4 example. I have provide everything which is necessary but when i run the example and enter the values into the console, nothing happens (pages 29 and 30).

Here is the grammar :

```
grammar ArrayInit;

init : '{' value ( ',' value)* '}';

value : init      | INT       ;
       INT : [0-9]+ ; WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
```

And here is the Test.java

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(System.in);

        ArrayInitLexer lexer = new ArrayInitLexer(input);

        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

        ArrayInitParser parser = new ArrayInitParser(tokens);

        ParseTree tree = parser.init();

        System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));


    }
}
```

Given input is : {1,{2,3},4}

The expected output is : ( init {(value 1), (value (init { (value 2), (value 3) })), (value 4)} )

Comment: It works well for me.

Comment: When I run the Test.java as java application and enter values into the console and hit Enter, nothing happens. It goes to newline. Do i miss something ?

Comment: Try change `System.in` to `"{1,{2,3},4}"`.